# How to make Pro*C cope with #warning directives?

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-pro-c

When I try to precompile a *.pc file that contains a #warning directive I recieve the following error:

> PCC-S-02014, Encountered the symbol "warning" when expecting one of the following: (bla bla bla).

Can I somehow convince Pro*C to ignore the thing if it doesn't know what to do with it? I can't remove the `#warning` directive as it's used in a header file that I can't change and must include.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the *Pro*C/C++ Programmer's Guide* (chapter 5 "Advanced Topics"), Pro*C silently ignores a number of preprocessor directives including #error and #pragma, but sadly not #warning.  Since your warning directives are included in a header file, you might be able to use the ORA_PROC macro:

```
#ifndef  ORA_PROC
#include <irrelevant.h>
#endif
```

For some reason, Pro*C errors out if you try to hide a straight #warning that way, however.

Answer (score 2):

use option `parse=none` with proc

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Pro*C only knows #if and #include.  My best advice would be to preprocess the file as part of your build process to remove stuff Pro*C won't like.  Something like

```
grep -v -E '^#(warning|pragma|define)' unchangeable.h >unchangeable.pc.h
```

My other advice would be to avoid the abomination which is Pro*C, but I'm guessing you're stuck with it...

Answer (score 0):

Jons Ericsons answer is correct.

There is a second circumstance where you may need to use that trick.

Some versions of Pro*c can't deal with include files that don't have a file extension.

The ORA_PROC constant is one workable solution to that problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

/bin/make -f /css/hwmig/pcprg/proc9i32.mk PROCFLAGS="sqlcheck=SEMANTICS userid=cssd/india09" PCCSRC=bic I_SYM=include= pc1
    proc sqlcheck=SEMANTICS userid=cssd/india09 iname=bic include=. include=/oracle/Ora92/precomp/public include=/oracle/Ora92/rdbms/public include=/oracle/Ora92/rdbms/demo include=/oracle/Ora92/plsql/public include=/oracle/Ora92/network/public

Pro*C/C++: Release 9.2.0.6.0 - Production on Tue Dec 2 14:05:38 2008

Copyright (c) 1982, 2002, Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.

System default option values taken from: /oracle/Ora92/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg

Syntax error at line 135, column 2, file /usr/include/standards.h:
Error at line 135, column 2 in file /usr/include/standards.h

## warning  The -qdfp option is required to process DFP code in headers.

.1
PCC-S-02014, Encountered the symbol "warning" when expecting one of the followin
g:

a numeric constant, newline, define, elif, else, endif,
   error, if, ifdef, ifndef, include, line, pragma, undef,
   an immediate preprocessor command, a C token,
The symbol "newline," was substituted for "warning" to continue.

Syntax error at line 30, column 7, file bic.pc:
Error at line 30, column 7 in file bic.pc
FILE  *fp;
......1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "*" when expecting one of the following:

; , = ( [
The symbol ";" was substituted for "*" to continue.

Error at line 0, column 0 in file bic.pc
PCC-F-02102, Fatal error while doing C preprocessing

Answer (score -1):

Remove below two lines from /usr/include/standards.h

## warning  The -qdfp option is required to process DFP code in headers.

## else

Answer (score -2):

Modify `/usr/include/standards.h`.
Delete the line `#warning  The -qdfp option is required to process DFP code in headers.`      The proc does not support the `#warning`，just `#else` `#if` etc.

Comment: This is *ABSOLUTELY POSITIVELY THE WRONG ANSWER*.
You should *NEVER*, under any circumstances, modify the system headers to fix an application bug.